# Cannot access newly created community in Salesforce

Tags: community

I created a community in my Salesforce developer account after setting up my domain. But i cannot access it. There is a message on communitiy page that "URL NO LONGER EXISTS". I can manage community though, but cannot access it. Is there anything am i missing ??
May be i am not member of community, but i tried adding myself as a member through data loader. It says duplicate values. It means i am already a member??

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps

In order to resolve the issue the following steps need to be taken
    Click on Setup | Customize | Communities | All Communities | Manage Communities | Administration
    Click Tabs or Pages.
    To use standard tabs, select Use Salesforce.com tabs.
    Save

Comment: I got tabs in community home page. But it is still saying URL NO LONGER EXISTS. Thanks